# Ошибки ссылок в Joomla при переходе на другой домен

Tags: url, joomla, домен

На хостинге было два домена. Стояла задача поменять их содержимое местами.

Сайт не редактировался, его только перенаправили на другой домен.

В следствии чего отвалилось несколько функциональных блоков, картинки на сайте перестали отображаться из-за неверного формирования пути к ним.

Сайт на Joomla. Ранее с этим движком не работал и совсем с ним не знаком.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой при переезде сайта? Подскажите решение, пожалуйста

Comment: Сам фреймворк Joomla - это очень мощный инструмент и при смене домена на сайте не должно быть проблем со ссылками т.к вся система работает через относительные пути, если, конечно, над сайтом работал тот, у которого руки растут из правильного места :)  Вам надо проверить файл в корне сайта, configuration.php, возможно там в параметре `live_site` указан старый домен, можно заменить или просто оставить пустым.